# fancyhead not in small caps

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, capitalization

The text in my fancyhead is written in small caps. I would like to have it not in small caps. How can I do?

This is my fancyhead:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a format similar to the one in the example page, you can do like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\format@sec@number}[2]{{\normalfont\upshape#1}#2}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\format@sec@number{\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \fi}{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{\format@sec@number{\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\z@\thesection. \fi}{#1}}}
\makeatother

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
```

I assume two-sided printing. Here are the header for an even and an odd page.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Use `\nouppercase`:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\nouppercase{\sl{\rightmark}}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\nouppercase{\sl{\leftmark}}}]{\rm\thepage}
\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

I prefer the use of `\itshape` over `\sl` and `\rmfamily` over `\rm`

```
\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr}
\lhead[\rmfamily\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\itshape\nouppercase\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\itshape\nouppercase\leftmark}]{\rmfamily\thepage}
\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

In this case `\rmfamily` looks superfluous.

Comment: Using `\itshape` or `\rmfamily` is not only a personal preference; the two letter commands should never be used: they exist only for compatibility with older documents and document classes may not implement them.

Comment: The replacement for `\sl` is `\slshape`, not `\itshape`.