# In fancyhdr, ensure every letters in chapter/title names are in lowercase

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, capitalization, small-caps

In designing novels, (Document-class Book `KOMA SCRIPT`) I prefer to use all-small-caps in the running heads. Please find the first example, where both `howards end` and `chapter 29` were all set in lowercase and old style numerals. I achieved this through `\nouppercase` and literally converted the necessary letters to lowercase, it looks tidy, has the small caps spacing between letters and good proportion with old style numerals.

i.e.

```
\fancyhead[EC]{\rmfamily \sc \small \nouppercase howards end}
```

[image: all lowercase with smallcaps]

However, in some design, normal title-caps are required for bookmarks and chapter title lettering. For instance, in Back to Methuselah, the chapter name needs to be set as `The Things Happens` with title caps. Here I cheated by setting them all in CAPs, so it looks tidy.

```
\fancyhead[OC]{\rmfamily \bf  \small \sc \leftmark }
```

[image: all uppercase]

Of course, setting all uppercase lost the lovely spacing that smallcaps will normally have and also the proportion with the old style numerals.

So here is my question, is there a way to stoutly make sure all the letters in headings are in lowercase even they came in as mix caps?

**Here is the minimal example:**

I'm using LyX, but the principle and code should be the same:

Load `fancyhdr` in document class `Book KOMA-Script` two side document. all other default.

```
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

\fancyhead[OC]{\rmfamily \small \nouppercase \leftmark}
```

Dummy text with chapter name `This is Mixing Caps` will produce the following example, *but* I want them to be `this is mixing caps` in the header only so that I can apply small caps on.
[image: example]

Comment: [`textcase`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textcase) provides `\MakeTextLowercase`; a counterpart to `\MakeUppercase` or `\MakeTextUppercase`. See the UK TeX FAQ entry [Case-changing oddities](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=casechange).

Comment: Did you try `\MakeLowercase{XXXXX}`? It works with `report`, for example.

Comment: @Werner I tried `\fancyhead[OC]{\rmfamily \bf  \small \nouppercase \MakeTextLowercase{\leftmark}}` (with or without `\nouppercase`) It produced error. citing too many }. I am with KOMA Script, Book Class. textcase loaded.

Comment: @Sigur It produced the same error as above.

Comment: Look at this similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87435/fancyhead-not-in-small-caps

Comment: Look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=no+uppercase+header+footers)

Comment: @egreg gave it a go, it still produced the output of "This is Mixed Cases" rather than the desirable "this is mixed cases". I copied the code exactly.

Comment: `\nouppercase` takes an argument, it's not a declaration. Can you make a complete example with the relevant code you're using?

Comment: @egreg a minimal example is added into the question. tx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo} % a font with old style figures

\usepackage{fancyhdr,textcase}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\footnotesize\scshape\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{\chaptername~\thechapter}}
```

[image]